# Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint "XXX" ..... Could not create constraint or index

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm setting up a new e-commerce project. I want every category has many sub category and these sub categories has many products in it. My product , category and sub category classes are here;

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class SubCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ItemsInCategory { get { return Products.Count; } }

    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class Product 
{

    public Product()
    {
        Attributes = new List<Attribute>();
        Reviews = new List<Review>();
    }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string BrandName { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public bool OnSale { get; set; }
    public int SalePercantage { get; set; }
    public decimal SalePrice { get; set; }

    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }

    public List<Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }
    public List<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}
```

While I'm trying to update database I'm getting this error :

Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Products_SubCategory_SubCategoryId' on table 'Products' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show us your foreign key definitions from your context?

Comment: It cannot be said from the posted model because the shown entities do not contain "cycles or multiple cascade paths". There must be something else causing it - either in `Attribute` / `Review` entities or some other common entity like `User` or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify in your context the one-to-many relationship , in your case a Product has one SubCategory and a SubCategory has many Product's

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
                .HasOne(d => d.SubCategory)
                .WithMany(p => p.Products)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.SubCategoryId);
```

Comment: Worked for me thnx ,